# $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)=A(X)$ for any open subset $U$ that is the complement of an irreducible variety of codimension at least $2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

I am trying to solve Exercise 3.15 in Gathmann's 2014 notes.
Given an irreducible affine variety $X$ such that $A(X)$ is UFD und $U$ like in the heading I want to show that the sheaf of regular functions on $U$ is already the whole coordinate ring $A(X)$.

From a previous exercise I know that regular functions on $U$ are given as a quotient of polynomials globally on $U$ if $A(X)$ is UFD i.e. $\varphi(x) = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ for all $x \in U$ and $f,g \in A(X)$. It seems reasonable to show that $f$ is a unit using the fact that this equation kind of holds in dimension $2$ but I have no idea how to proceed at this point.

Comment: This is [algebraic Hartogs's Lemma](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class20.pdf).

Comment: For a solution phrased in terms of scheme: let $R = \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ then $X=\text{Spec} R$, then $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in U} R_\mathfrak{p}$, assumption on $U$ says it contains all prime ideals of height $1$, then use a result commutative algebra: for an integrally closed Noethrian ring (in particular, Noetherian UFD), intersection of localizations at height 1 prime ideals is the ring itself.

Comment: @pisco that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 5):

This is a community wiki answer recording the discussion from the comments, in order that this question might be marked as answered (once this post is upvoted or accepted).

> This is [algebraic Hartogs's Lemma](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/0708-216/216class20.pdf). – **Richard D. James**
>
> For a solution phrased in terms of scheme: let $R=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ then $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$, then $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in U} R_\mathfrak{p}$, assumption on $U$ says it contains all prime ideals of height 1, then use a result commutative algebra: for an integrally closed Noethrian ring (in particular, Noetherian UFD), intersection of localizations at height 1 prime ideals is the ring itself. – **pisco**